# Pandas: Sum and Aggregate Column Values based on three different other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on the [Kaggle E-Commerce-Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/carrie1/ecommerce-data). In order to prepare the data for a neural network for future sales prediction, I need to aggregate the Quantity of a specific product sales on every day. My code right now looks the following...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data_date.csv', encoding='cp1252')
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0,3,7,8]], axis=1)
print(df.head(5))
```

this outputs the following...

```
InvoiceNo StockCode  Quantity InvoiceDate  UnitPrice
0    536365    85123A         6  2010-12-01       2.55
1    536365     71053         6  2010-12-01       3.39
2    536365    84406B         8  2010-12-01       2.75
3    536365    84029G         6  2010-12-01       3.39
4    536365    84029E         6  2010-12-01       3.39
```

now my aim is to aggregate e.g. the `Quantity` of `StockCode` Item 71053 on `InvoideDate` 2010-12-01. But this is just an example, what I need is an overview, how many Items of every StockCode have been sold each day.

I tried plenty of `groupy`-operations and found an answer on SO, which brought me pretty close to the desired output...

```
df["Quantity"] = df.groupby(["InvoiceDate", "StockCode"])["Quantity"].transform(sum)
print(df.head(5))
```

this gives me the following output...

```
InvoiceNo StockCode  Quantity InvoiceDate  UnitPrice
0    536365    85123A       454  2010-12-01       2.55
1    536365     71053        33  2010-12-01       3.39
2    536365    84406B        40  2010-12-01       2.75
3    536365    84029G        59  2010-12-01       3.39
4    536365    84029E       551  2010-12-01       3.39
```

looks good already, but when I did a test with a specific `StockCode`, it is still putting the same `Quantity` on different rows and not really aggregating it. See example below...

```
print(df.loc[df['StockCode']=='22632'])
```

outputs...

```
InvoiceNo StockCode  Quantity InvoiceDate  UnitPrice
8         536366     22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
47        536372     22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
84        536377     22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
257       536394     22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
304       536398     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
315       536399     22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
433       536407     22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
664       536415     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
704       536423     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
879       536477     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
952       536520     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
1029      536522     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
1066      536522     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
1260      536532     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
1399      536539     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
1441     C536543     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
1628      536544     22632       233  2010-12-01       4.21
2139      536561     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
2183      536567     22632       233  2010-12-01       2.10
2776      536592     22632       233  2010-12-01       4.21
3130      536601     22632       169  2010-12-02       1.85
```

So how can I manipulate the data so that it shows the quanity of 233 on one row, regardless of `UnitPrice` and `InvoiceNo`?

like this?

```
InvoiceNo StockCode  Quantity InvoiceDate  UnitPrice
    8         536366     22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
    3130      536601     22632       169  2010-12-02       1.85
```

also I would be interested if there is a way to group the Sales per `StockCode` and `InvoiceDate` AND on the different `UnitPrices`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) if want first rows only per columns `InvoiceDate` and `StockCode`:

```
df["Quantity"] = df.groupby(["InvoiceDate", "StockCode"])["Quantity"].transform(sum)
df11 = df.drop_duplicates(['InvoiceDate','StockCode'])
print (df11)
     InvoiceNo  StockCode  Quantity InvoiceDate  UnitPrice
8       536366      22632       233  2010-12-01       1.85
3130    536601      22632       169  2010-12-02       1.85
```

Same solution with aggregation is specify aggregate function `first`:

```
df11 = (df.groupby(["InvoiceDate", "StockCode"], as_index=False)
         .agg({'Quantity': 'sum', 'UnitPrice':'first', 'InvoiceNo': 'first'})
         .reindex(columns=df.columns))
print (df11)
  InvoiceNo  StockCode  Quantity InvoiceDate  UnitPrice
0    536366      22632      4660  2010-12-01       1.85
1    536601      22632       169  2010-12-02       1.85
```

Old answer:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["InvoiceDate", "StockCode"], as_index=False)["Quantity"].sum()
print (df1)
  InvoiceDate StockCode  Quantity
0  2010-12-01     71053         6
1  2010-12-01    84029E         6
2  2010-12-01    84029G         6
3  2010-12-01    84406B         8
4  2010-12-01    85123A         6
```

But if want all columns in output is necessary add them to `groupby` or specify aggregate functions for each columns:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(["InvoiceNo","InvoiceDate", "StockCode"], as_index=False)
               ['Quantity','UnitPrice'].sum())
print (df2)
   InvoiceNo InvoiceDate StockCode  Quantity  UnitPrice
0     536365  2010-12-01     71053         6       3.39
1     536365  2010-12-01    84029E         6       3.39
2     536365  2010-12-01    84029G         6       3.39
3     536365  2010-12-01    84406B         8       2.75
4     536365  2010-12-01    85123A         6       2.55
```

Or specify for each column aggregate function like:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(["InvoiceDate", "StockCode"], as_index=False)
         .agg({'Quantity': 'sum', 'UnitPrice':'mean', 'InvoiceNo': 'first'}))
print (df2)
  InvoiceDate StockCode  Quantity  UnitPrice  InvoiceNo
0  2010-12-01     71053         6       3.39     536365
1  2010-12-01    84029E         6       3.39     536365
2  2010-12-01    84029G         6       3.39     536365
3  2010-12-01    84406B         8       2.75     536365
4  2010-12-01    85123A         6       2.55     536365
```

Comment: if I run above code, the `Quantity` is replaced by the `InvoiceNo`. I was pretty satisfied with the output of my own function, which used the `.transform(sum)` at the end, but I just need a way to show only one row and not multiple rows the the same `InvoiceDate` and `StockCode`.

Comment: yes, this looks good! Do you know how the mean of the Price can be used like you tried to show before? so can I apply the `.agg` the my code or do I need to rewrite it?

Comment: @Cut7er - I think old solutions should be helpful, so added to answer too ;)

Comment: ok great, will try to play around with it. But dropping dupes was the first good idea, I already implemented :-)

Comment: @Cut7er - It is same like `(df.groupby(["InvoiceDate", "StockCode"], as_index=False)
         .agg({'Quantity': 'sum', 'UnitPrice':'first', 'InvoiceNo': 'first'})
         .reindex(columns=df.columns))` - you aggregate first value of another columns - added to answer.